# Showing images from an array of file names using react native Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

I have made a dummy data file called avatars in the folder assets/dummy-data/Avatars.ts.

```
export default [
    {id: 1, levels: ["pichu", "picachu", "raichu"]},
    {id: 2, levels: ["charmander", "charmeleon", "charizard"]},
    {id: 3, levels: ["totodile", "croconaw", "feraligatr"]},
    {id: 4, levels: ["squirtle", "wartortle", "blastoise"]},
    {id: 5, levels: ["bulbasaur", "ivysaur", "venusaur"]},
    {id: 6, levels: ["cyndaquil", "quilava", "typhlosion"]},
    {id: 7, levels: ["pidgey", "pidgeotto", "pidgeot"]},
    {id: 8, levels: ["turtwig", "grotle", "torterra"]},
    {id: 9, levels: ["igglybuff", "jigglypuff", "wigglytuff"]},
    {id: 10, levels: ["cleffa", "iclefairy", "clefable"]},
    {id: 11, levels: ["litten", "torracat", "incineroar"]},
    {id: 12, levels: ["nidoran", "nidorina", "vnidoqueen"]},
]
```

What I want to do is to load this data in another file, and there make a Flatlist component with them. My code is:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native'
import Avatars from '../assets/dummy-data/Avatars'

const OnboardingScreen = () => {
    const test = "charizard"
    console.log(Avatars)
    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList
                data = {Avatars}
                renderItem = {
                    ({item}) =>
                        (
                            <Image source={require(`../assets/images/avatars/${{item}.levels[0]}pichu.jpg`)} />
                        )
                }
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default OnboardingScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

And this is the error that I get:
[Screen capture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddJAQ.png)

Thank you

Comment: you have added pichu.jpg at the end, i think that is causing the issue.
if removing it does not fix it then try to console log the path you are giving to Image and make sure its correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic images are not supported in React Native. Currently, support only [static image resources](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources) because the image name in require has to be known statically.

```
// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />
```

In order to to fix your problem change your avatar data as below

```
export default [
    {
        id: 1, levels: [
            require('./assets/images/avatars/pichu.jpg'),
            require('./assets/images/avatars/picachu.jpg'),
            require('./assets/images/avatars/raichu.jpg')
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2, levels: [
            require('./assets/images/avatars/charmander.jpg'),
            require('./assets/images/avatars/charmeleon.jpg'),
            require('./assets/images/avatars/charizard.jpg')
        ]
    },
]
```

then you can render your images

```
<Image source={item.levels[0]} />
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.